# Image not taking full div space for rounded image

Tags: html, css

I have a div set as parent and an `img` tag inside it. The image is not taking full width when applied shadow to div. I have tried giving the image z-index in order to pop out a little bit but not helping in this case.

I don't understand why it is working for a square image and not an already rounded image.

```css
.profile-card__img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px #6c44fc, 0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(107, 74, 255, 0.5);
}

.profile-card__img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-card__img">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/256/256/2*xhm2q3S8_kRKnrHumo3Rvg.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there is a reason why you're not using `border` or `outline` for your shadow with a rgba value?

Comment: no particular reason as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real answer, but I can't really see what you mean. Is it the slight white border between the image and the border-like box-shadow? Because as you can see, by looking at the red dashed line in the first snippet below, the images are at the same place, meaning they all have the same width.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.red-vertical-dash {
  position: absolute;
  left: 52%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px dashed red;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.profile-card__img.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px #6c44fc, 0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(107, 74, 255, 0.5);
}

.profile-card__img.rounded,
.profile-card__img.rounded img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.profile-card__img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-card__img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-vertical-dash"></div>

  <div class="profile-card__img">
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/256/256/2*xhm2q3S8_kRKnrHumo3Rvg.png">
  </div>

  <div class="shadow rounded profile-card__img">
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/256/256/2*xhm2q3S8_kRKnrHumo3Rvg.png">
  </div>

  <div class="shadow profile-card__img">
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/256/256/2*xhm2q3S8_kRKnrHumo3Rvg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way could be to add the image as a background image, but I'm guessing that the image url is declared dynamically so that wont be sufficient, and I honestly don't know what that would achieve, apart from less code.

```css
.profile-card__img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px #6c44fc, 0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(107, 74, 255, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(-50%);

  /* new code */
  background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/256/256/2*xhm2q3S8_kRKnrHumo3Rvg.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="profile-card__img"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this -

```css
.profile-card__img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px #6c44fc, 0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(107, 74, 255, 0.5);
}

.profile-card__img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-card__img">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/fit/c/256/256/2*xhm2q3S8_kRKnrHumo3Rvg.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did to the questioner actually learns something.

Comment: Yes. But it didn't address my query. Can you explain? Also, you have used the square image which was already posted. Can you use the one given in imgur link

Comment: I think because the image has also border-radius